# Property Placeholder for Imports/Bean Refs

Tags: spring

Can I use a property loaded from property-placeholder to make a context import dynamic?

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:/enterprise.properties"/>
<import resource="classpath*:/Fsb${jdbc.ctxType?:Jdbc}-context.xml"/>
```

Properties File

```
jdbc.ctxType=JTA
```

So this way I could change the type of context file that is loaded based on a property.

Also, can I do the same thing to make a bean ref name dynamic?

```
<bean id="personBusinessService" class="com.foo.PersonBusinessServiceImpl"
          p:personUidDataService-ref="personUidDataService${personUidDataService.sib?:Api}" 
          p:identifierLookupSearchService-ref="identifierLookupSearchService${identifierLookupSearchService.sib?:Api}"  
          p:contactPointBusinessService-ref="contactPointBusinessService${contactPointBusinessService.sib?:Api}"
/>
```

Properties File

```
personUidDataService.sib=Stub
```

Jay

--------------------Update example of property for ref-------------------------

I created a property file with the following entry:

```
addressLookupSearchService.sib=DaoMock
```

Then I have the following configuration in a Spring Context File:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:/simple.properties"/>

<!-- EntityManager will be injected into DAO by JPA annotations -->
<bean id="addressSearchDao" class="com.foo.AddressSearchDaoImpl"/>

<bean id="addressSearchDaoMock" class="com.foo.MockAddressSearchDaoImpl"/>

<bean id="addressLookupSearchService" class="com.foo.AddressLookupSearchServiceImpl"
    p:baseDao-ref="addressSearch${addressLookupSearchService.sib?:Dao}"/>
```

And addressSearch${addressLookupSearchService.sib?:Dao} doesn't work, it always defaults to
the bean id of addressSearchDao even if my property says it should set to addressSearchDaoMock.

Any thoughts as to what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a similar question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1520055/367285) one.

[Imports](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.M1/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-xml-import) are resolved **before** bean (property-placeholder) creation, so you can not use the property file to define properties which you want to use in an import statement. In this case you have to set the property as `system property` (`-Djdbc.ctxType=JTA`) (have a look at the link - paragraph *Note*).

But using the property file properties in bean definitions works fine - that's what they are for :-)

**Update**: Since Spring 3.1 the [Unified Property Management](http://spring.io/blog/2011/02/15/spring-3-1-m1-unified-property-management/) allows to use properties even in imports (thanks @Jay Blanton for mentioning this in the comments).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion...I am looking at the import information.  As far as the bean reference using a property, I updated the question to show an example of what I am trying to do...and it doesn't seem to be working for me.

Comment: Looks like I found the answer.  I thought the syntax was ?: for default values.  But the syntax that worked was, ${addressLookupSearchService.sib:Dao} without the question mark.  Based on this JIRA - https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-4785.

Comment: Good that it works now. Your update question changed the focus of the question a bit - I did not notice your special problems (with using the default value) first.

Comment: Very cool feature in 3.1 - which looks like it can solve the property replacement for imports...http://blog.springsource.com/2011/02/15/spring-3-1-m1-unified-property-management/

Comment: SOLUTION: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16481206/spring-property-placeholder-not-working

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you can. You can use expressions in imports and injections.