# Spring property placeholder not working

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, properties

I've read similar issues on the stackoverflow.com, but none of the solutions helped me.
The following configuration I use (maven project structure):
the `src/main/resources/properties/app.properties` file

```
#possible values: dev test prod
mode: dev
```

In the Spring configuration:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:properties/app.properties"/>
<import resource="classpath:/spring/db/${mode}-datasource-config.xml"/>
```

Based on the value of `${mode}` I want to import the corresponding datasource configuration file.

When I run the embedded tomcat7 using the `mvn clean install tomcat7:run` command I'm getting the error:

```
10, 2013 5:52:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet /SpringWebFlow threw load() exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'mode' in string value "classpath:/spring/db/${mode}-datasource-config.xml"
```

The `target/classes/properties/app.properties` file exists.

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA and in the editor I can click on the "${mode}" in `<import resource="classpath:/spring/db/${mode}-datasource-config.xml"/>` and see its value in the property file. Also the editor itself change `${mode}` onto the grey colored `dev` showing it can recognize the property value. In the editor I see: `<import resource="classpath:/spring/db/dev-datasource-config.xml"/>`

Any ideas why I'm getting the error and how it can be resolved?

Comment: Which Spring version do you use: <3.1 or >=3.1?

Comment: @Ralph, <spring.version>3.2.2.RELEASE</spring.version>

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Property placeholders in imports are resolved against enviroment variables or system properties only.

Since version 3.1 you can use an `ApplicationContextInitializer` to add `PropertySources` to the `Enviroment` that will solve your problem.

see http://blog.springsource.org/2011/02/15/spring-3-1-m1-unified-property-management/

Other option to do the same is using profiles: http://blog.springsource.org/2011/02/14/spring-3-1-m1-introducing-profile/

**Edit**

For example:

Add the initializer to web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextInitializerClasses</param-name>
    <param-value>foo.bar.AppContextInitializer</param-value>
</context-param>
```

And the initializer:

```
public class AppContextInitializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableWebApplicationContext> {

        @Override
        public void initialize(ConfigurableWebApplicationContext applicationContext) {
            Properties props;
            try {
                props = PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadAllProperties("/some/path");
                PropertiesPropertySource ps = new PropertiesPropertySource("profile", props);
                applicationContext.getEnvironment().getPropertySources().addFirst(ps);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // handle error
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not strong in Spring. Can I setup ApplicationContextInitializer declatively in the Spring config file? I don't think one need to  implement it for property files loading only. Cannot find any example. I can see only java implementations.

Comment: No, you can't do it declaratively. `PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer` or `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` are `BeanFactoryPostProcessors` so imports are parsed before.

Comment: +1: for the link http://blog.springsource.org/2011/02/15/spring-3-1-m1-unified-property-management/

Comment: @JoseLuisMartin, please tell me, how can I setup ApplicationContextInitializer in the java-based configuration within web environment. When Disptacher servlet is created

Comment: For JavaConfig, look at `@PropertySource` annotation

Answer (score 2):

Is this properties file format valid? I think you should use following contents for `app.properties`:

```
#possible values: dev test prod
mode=dev
```