# Can SpEL be used with import statements in spring xml configuration

Tags: spring

I am trying to use SpEL in import statement in spring xml configuration. 
I am trying to do this

```
<import resource="classpath*:/'#{'${enable.mass.quote.service:false}'=='true' ? 'massquoting' : 'quoting'}'-beans.xml"/>
```

but it is not working, any suggestions please

Comment: Howabout to remove quotes around SpEL ?

Comment: All those combinations already tried, no progress, so just want to confirm whether it is possible to use sPeL in import or not?
has anyone use this before?

Answer (score 4):

Actually you are right: `<import resource>` doesn't support SpEL, but it supports `property-placeholders`:

```
// Resolve system properties: e.g. "${user.dir}"
location = environment.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(location);
```

So, for your case it might look like:

```
<import resource="classpath*:/${enable.mass.quote.service:quoting}-beans.xml"/>
```

where `enable.mass.quote.service` should have value `massquoting`.

If you have more high condition, e.g. `enable.mass.quote.service=true`, you should rely on `Spring Profiles`:

```
<beans profile="service">
    <import resource="classpath*:/massquoting-beans.xml"/>
</beans>

<beans profile="nonService">
    <import resource="classpath*:/quoting-beans.xml"/>
</beans>
```

Comment: I have tried with the profiles also, see config below

Answer (score 1):

I too came across this requirement and turns out the answer is NO. SpEL or placeholders cannot be used in Spring import statements because the import happens before the placeholders/expressions are evaluated and substituted. Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410017/property-placeholder-for-imports-bean-refs). Spring profiles is the answer just that Spring profiles were floated beginning Spring 3.1.x so when using an older version of Spring one might have to take on the onerous task of writing custom [namespaces and their handlers](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/extensible-xml.html).