# Use bean value as property in spring context

Tags: java, spring

I am creating my own property conditionally:

```
<bean id="path" class="java.lang.String">
    <constructor-arg value="#{ systemProperties['mySystemProperty'] == 'A' ? 'pathB' : 'pathC'}" />
</bean>
```

Later I want to use it in referencing a resource:

```
<import resource="${path}/my-webapp-config.xml" />    // doesn't work
```

or

```
<import resource="#{path}/my-webapp-config.xml" />    // doesn't work
```

But this does not work that way... How can I reference the bean value of "path" in the path to a resource?

I don't want to use a property configurer (is already in use for other purpose). And I also don't want to write my own `CustomPropertyConfigurer`.  I only want to use the value of the bean. Is that possible in an easy way?

EDIT

It's possible to use the expression

```
#{ systemProperties['mySystemProperty'] == 'A' ? 'pathB' : 'pathC'}
```

directly in the path, but the problem is that it's not working that way. I assume, this is due to the fact that the string comparison does not work:

```
#{ systemProperties['mySystemProperty'] == 'A'
```

Can somebody say how to do a String comparison in a spring context with spEL?

UPDATE
It is probably not the String comparison that does not work but the whole line does nothing. I tried it the following way without result:

```
<import resource="#{ true ? 'pathB' : 'pathC'}/myConfig.xml"/>
```

Actually, the resource is never read - and there is also no complain about not finding "myConfig.xml" or the like. As a JNDI-datasource is defined in there, the actual error message is always:

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc:mydatabasepath] is not bound in this Context
```

I also tried:

```
<import resource="#{systemProperties['mySystemProperty']}/myConfig.x‌​ml" />
```

And got the error:

```
[file:/home/tomcat/....../#{systemProperties['mySystemProperty']}/myConfig.xml] is invalid; ... org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog.
```

**UPDATE**

I couldn't make it work, but I am using spring profiles instead now. That is much more appropriate for my case and much easier.

It looks like this:

```
<beans profile="live">
    <!-- include live resources --/>
</beans>

<beans profile="!live">
    <!-- include dev resources --/>
</beans>
```

The tomcat is started with the argument:

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=dev
```

Comment: Have you tried tweaking the searchSystemEnvironment and systemPropertiesModeName properties of the existing placeholder configuration? It will allow you to use your System properties with the placeholder syntax.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by that. Can you be more specific, please?

Comment: There's a provision in PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer to include System properties. It would allow you to use System properties using placeholder syntax. Something like ${mySystemProperty}. Will that be useful for you in anyways?

Comment: I can't use mySystemProperty directly because I am creating the path conditionally. I only need to know how to create a property conditionally and use it later as a normal property.

Comment: Ok, Is that intermediate bean necessary? Doesn't this work? <import resource="#{ systemProperties['mySystemProperty'] == 'A' ? 'pathB' : 'pathC'}/my-webapp-config.xml" />

Comment: Mmh... it's an idea... Right now I only use "path" two times, so it would be nice to have a property but not absolutely necessary. I tried it, can't yet make it all working but it seems to work that way generally.

Comment: The string comparison #{ systemProperties['mySystemProperty'] == 'A'  does not seem to work.

Comment: Ok. Please refer to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23650771/can-spel-be-used-with-import-statements-in-spring-xml-configuration I was able to evaluate your SPEL successfully in other tags except import.