# Spring bean name/id property placeholder resolution

Tags: java, spring

Is it possible to use placeholders defined in the property files for bean names and ids?

**xml file**

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <util:list>
            <value>classpath:propertyFile.properties</value>
        </util:list>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean name="${placeholderName}">
    <property name="prop" value="value"/>
</bean>
```

**propertyFile.properties**

```
placeholderName=beanName
```

**[Edit] Error:**

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name '${placeholderName}'
>
> Cannot resolve reference to bean 'beanName' while setting bean
>   property 'prop';
>
> nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   bean named 'beanName' is defined

Comment: Did you tried similar set up?

Comment: @Henry What is the question here? Does this code work/not work? Are there any errors that you are seeing while running this?

Comment: Using property file properties in bean definition works. Refer to a similar link http://stackoverflow.com/a/5411217/1925997. Possible Duplicate.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520055/import-spring-config-file-based-on-property-in-properties-file