# Java Spring - Import resource based on Placeholder Expression

Tags: java, spring

In Spring, I'd like to do the following:

```
<import resource="${resourceFile}" />
```

However, 'resourceFile' is not evaluated by the import.

The reason why I need it to work is I defined to two different resourceFiles:
resources-serviceA.xml
resources-serviceB.xml

Each of the above files define different sets of beans. When running ServiceA, I wouldn't need the beans needed just for ServiceB and hence I do not want to create them.

Any pointers on how to accomplish this?

We are using Spring 3.0.

Comment: At what point are you making the decision as to whether your application is running service A or B? I'm curious as to why you're okay with changing a .properties file but not a similar XML file.

Answer (score 1):

Spring 3.0 can not evaluate properties inside `import` tag, evaluating those was one of the new features of Spring 3.1 (in 2011) 
See [Spring 3.1 M1: Unified Property Management](http://spring.io/blog/2011/02/15/spring-3-1-m1-unified-property-management/)

So basically you should use the actual version of Spring. Spring 3.1+ also introduced [bean profiles](http://spring.io/blog/2011/02/11/spring-framework-3-1-m1-released/), so you can define ServiceA and ServiceB in different profiles.

If you are interested how this problem was solved by users of Spring 3.0 you can look at [Import Spring config file based on property in .properties file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520055/import-spring-config-file-based-on-property-in-properties-file) but keep in mind that Spring 3.0 is 3 years old now, it's suspicious to make changes in the basic bootstrapping configuration of the 3yo project, consider switching to Spring 4.0+.