# Spring applicationcontext.xml read a properties file from path existing in other classpath porperties

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, properties

i need to read properties  from a properties file whose path is indicated in other properties file.

The first properties file have a key with the path of the other properties. This file is in my classpath. Ej:

configpathfile.properties

```
> configpath=pathToMyConfigFile/config.properties
```

The config.properties file can be in anywhere in the server.

config.properties

```
> database.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
> database.url=jdbc\:postgresql\://172.20.7.177\:5432/administrados
> database.username=postgres database.password=postgres
```

I have made some attemps, but all failed:

First attemp:

In my applicationContext.xml

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:configpathfile.properties,file:${configpath}"/>

<bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close" id="dataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driverClassName}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${database.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${database.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}"/>
</bean>
```

When tomcat startup, I get the error :

Could not load properties; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: ${configpath} (No existe el archivo o el directorio)

Second attemp:

In my applicationContext.xml

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:configpathfile.properties"/>

<bean id="myProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
        <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
            <property name="locations" value="file:${ruta}" >

    </bean>

<bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close" id="dataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driverClassName}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${database.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${database.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}"/>
</bean>
```

but it fails, because it can't find the properties.

How is the best approach for this task?
Thanks.

Comment: hope you are not missing closing tag here `<property name="locations" value="file:${ruta}" >`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520055/import-spring-config-file-based-on-property-in-properties-file. This question seems to be your exact same question

Comment: thanks Vihar, In real code the tag is cosed.